Mounting QNAP virtual machine backup to recover files
unfortunately my QNAP NAS dies due to a physical defect. I had virtual machines running on the NAS which are backed up.
I urgently need some files out of the file system but I'm failing to mount anything here.
That is the file structure of the backup:
./Server4.1701522057
./.a3b3b9b0-bf88-45aa-b038-de19365f2674.meta/a3b3b9b0-bf88-45aa-b038-de19365f2674.xml
./.a3b3b9b0-bf88-45aa-b038-de19365f2674.meta/snapshot/1701522057.xml
./.a3b3b9b0-bf88-45aa-b038-de19365f2674.meta/snapshot/1701522057.state
./Server4.1693051222
./.a3b3b9b0-bf88-45aa-b038-de19365f2674.meta/snapshot/1693051222.xml
./.a3b3b9b0-bf88-45aa-b038-de19365f2674.meta/snapshot/1693051222.state
./.a3b3b9b0-bf88-45aa-b038-de19365f2674.meta/devices.json
./Server4.1688817606
./.a3b3b9b0-bf88-45aa-b038-de19365f2674.meta/snapshot/1688817606.xml
./.a3b3b9b0-bf88-45aa-b038-de19365f2674.meta/snapshot/1688817606.state
./.a3b3b9b0-bf88-45aa-b038-de19365f2674.meta/snapshot/1664126194.xml
./.a3b3b9b0-bf88-45aa-b038-de19365f2674.meta/snapshot/1664126194.state
./.a3b3b9b0-bf88-45aa-b038-de19365f2674.meta/snapshot/1664108142.xml
./.a3b3b9b0-bf88-45aa-b038-de19365f2674.meta/snapshot/1664108142.state

What I tried: I'm not that familiar with KVM and the file structures. I thought I will mount the snapshots as raw files. Unfortunately I cannot mount a snapshot. The files of "Server4.***" are pretty small so probably that not the files I was searching for. I have tried to mount the snapshots or files like described here: How to view live file system of QEMU/KVM VM externally? But there do not seem to be partitions on, only a device /dev/sda with an unknown file format.
Any idea on how I can mount a certain disk or snapshot that I can copy off some files? OS on the guest is Linux/Ubuntu 22.04.

version of Ubuntu? [edit] to your question please

22.04 LTS (not quite sure if it is .2 or .3...
